# Rails 3.0 + Test::Unit - I18n.locale diverges from config.i18n.default_locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, testunit

If I put the following in my unit test:

```
puts Inventarizace::Application.config.i18n.default_locale
puts I18n.locale
```

i get :cz for the first one (as expected), but :en for the second, resulting in locale lookup failures (with keys starting with 'en.'), since this is a czech app and not all keys are translated to english. This is a legacy app which I just upgraded from rails 2.3 to 3.0, don't know if this worked before, since I found this out after I broke that test during the upgrade. Can provide more info if needed. Thanks

Comment: I had similar problems, and could not determine the root cause, so I just set the locale in the setup of TestCase, like this:

    module ActiveSupport
      class TestCase
        def setup
          I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
        end
      end
    end

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this would probably work, but if I understand Test::Unit right, this means I need to call super in every inherited TestCase setup method. But since we're using shoulda-context with its setup block, this probably happens already. I wouldn't like this as a permanent solution but since we'll need to move to minitest/RSpec and upgrade rails further up, I'll probably go this way. Still I'd like to know the actual cause.